Is there any nesting level of tuplets above which any tuplets can be rewritten with lower-level nested tuplets?
Tuplets can be nested. I read:

In Dorico Pro, there is no limit to the number of levels you can have in nested tuplets

This made me wonder: Is there any nesting level of tuplets above which any nested tuplets of that level or higher could be rewritten with lower-level nested tuplets?

Below is an example for "rewritten with lower-level nested tuplets". These 3-level nested tuplets:

can be equivalently written as 2-level next tuplets:

As Brian Chandler commented, in the upper version the last semiquaver is 1/5 of a triplet, whereas in the lower version it is 2/9 of the triplet, which is different. But you get the idea of what I mean by "rewritten with lower-level nested tuplets".

Your question is not about music, since in practive no-one could read more than about two levels. But it might be a mathematical puzzle question (to which the answer is almost certainly "No"). First, however, you need to show your working: in the upper version the last semiquaver is 1/5 of a triplet, whereas in the lower version it is 2/9 of the triplet, which is different.

@BrianChandler A computer could. Thanks, point taken, question edited.

Sorry: to correct mysefl, the answer is obviously "Yes, 1 level". You simply take the LCM of all the n's in the n-tuples and multiply out. So your 5- and 7-tuples would become a 35-tuple.

I question the premise that the two notations are equivalent. For example, in the first example, the 5-tuplet takes the time of 2/3 of a beat, so the sixteenth note represents 2/15 of a beat. However, in the second example, the 9-tuplet takes the time of 2/3 of a beat, so the sixteenth note represents 2/27 of a beat.

@Aaron thanks, not a premise, just an (incorrect) example to explain the meaning of "rewritten with lower-level nested tuplets". While incorrect, it nevertheless served its purpose. If no correct example exists, then the answer is negative.

@FranckDernoncourt In that case, the problem is that the video makes no claim that the two notations are equivalent, just that they're "virtually" equivalent.

@Aaron ah my bad, I must have misheard, thanks!

(Note that in the video used for the OP demonstration, the narrator says "virtually" equivalent, not actually equivalent.)

Any set of nested tuplets can be rewritten as a single tuplet whose size is found by multiplying all of levels of the original.
In the case of the first example, it would be a 2 x 3 x 5 x 7 = 210-tuplet (the 2x comes from the fact that the tuplet represents two beats).

Each quarter note = 70/210 (total: 140/210)
The singleton 16th note = 35/210
Each sixteenth note from the 7-tuplet (to be rewritten as 32nd notes for clarity) = 5/210 (total: 35/210)


I don't think you need to multiply by 2*, but you are correct that you have to multiply all of the n in the n-tuplets, not take the least common multiple as I said in my comment. (A triplet within a triplet has to become a 9-tuplet.) (* A triplet over 2 beats is a triplet, not a 6-tuplet.)

@BrianChandler It's not a 6-tuplet, but it's equivalent to one.
